# Alternate Interpreters for Script

Tags: bash, gnuplot, hashbang

I have a script that I'm running on two computers. The first line of the code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
```

On the second computer, I want to use a version of GNUplot stored at `$HOME/bin/gnuplot`.

`$HOME/bin` is included in the second computer's `$PATH` variable, so I tried starting the script with a generic call to GNUplot:

```
#!gnuplot -p
```

but this didn't work because the script then searched for `./gnuplot`.

Is there a way to make the header line the same for both computers? I'd prefer that the solution be somehow contained to that one line, without the need for the script to differentiate between the computers or for me to tell it which computer it is on.

Answer (score 1):

`#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot` makes it more [portable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Portability).

Comment: Wrikken, this works just fine! But... I was _actually_ calling `gnuplot -p`, but had removed the flag to simplify the question. When I try `#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot -p` it tells me there is no such file or directory. Is there a way around this? I'm using Linux.

Comment: I read the mailing list [here](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/netbsd-users/2008/11/10/msg002390.html) and see that there are decent reasons why I may be expecting too much of `/usr/bin/env` and `#!` in general. Still, it would be nice if it worked.

Comment: Not in the shebang AFAIK, but I gather you could create a `.gnuplot` file which sets the default terminal and it's persistence.

Answer (score 1):

`#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot` is a more portable way of expressing the interpreter, as noted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Portability) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15234117/752843).

However, this introduces a problem you may not expect.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
```

makes a persistent GNUplot window, but running

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot -p
```

which would seem like the obvious portable alternative doesn't work.

Some reasons for this are discussed [here](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/netbsd-users/2008/11/10/msg002390.html), but there doesn't really seem to be a way around it: arguments and `/usr/bin/env` don't really get along.

In the particular case of the `-p` flag, it is best to use

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
```

and then include the line

```
set term x11 persist
```

in your GNUplot script, which will do the same thing.

Comment: What about the `-c` callable flag to pass arguments to *gnuplot*?

Comment: I've just found out that *OSX*'s `env` do support arguments... Still, Debian's does not...

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
```

See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) for some discussion of the advantages and drawbacks of this method.

But in your case, you need to pass a `-p` argument to `gnuplot` -- and the `#!` line doesn't handle that syntax.  You can use

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
```

but if you try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot -p
```

it will probably try to execute something named `gnuplot -p`, which of course doesn't exist (it passes `"gnuplot -p"` as a single argument to `/usr/bin/env`).

A solution I've used is to write an installation script that modifies the `#!` line for each system. Figuring out how to do that is left as an exercise.

If your home directory has the same full path name on both computers, you can do this:

```
#!/home/yourname/bin/gnuplot -p
```

On the computer where `gnuplot` lives in `$HOME/bin`, this does just what you want.  On the other one, where you want to use `/usr/bin/gnuplot`, create `$HOME/bin/gnuplot` as a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/gnuplot`:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gnuplot ~/bin/gnuplot
```

If you don't want to mess with your `$HOME/bin` directory on both machines, or if your `$HOME` has a different full path name, pick some other directory.  For example, you might install it in `/tmp/yourname/bin` on both machines:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/yourname/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/gnuplot /tmp/yourname/bin/gnuplot # on one machine, OR
ln -s ~/bin/gnuplot /tmp/yourname/bin/gnuplot    # on the other
```

and use:

```
#!/tmp/yourname/bin/gnuplot -p
```

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer, Keith. I've elected to use the command `set term x11 persist` within my script, which alleviates the problem with needing the `-p` argument.